# Cosa significa "vegeto" nell'espressione “sono vivo e vegeto”

Tags: word-meaning

Si usa l'espressione "Sono vivo e vegeto" per esprimere il fatto di stare bene. Però cercando sul dizionario, sotto "vegetare" si trova la definizione:

> Vivere in uno stato di incoscienza, limitandosi ad adempiere alle funzioni biologiche

Non è una definizione che rimanda a uno stato di salute.

Qual è dunque il significato di "vegeto" in questa situazione, qual è la sua origine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Non è una voce verbale, è l'aggettivo “[vegeto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vegeto/)”: «Che è in pieno vigore, che ha bell’aspetto e florida salute» (Treccani), dal latino *vegēre*, «essere vivace».

Answer (score 1):

Da "Il Nuovo Ragazzini/Biagi - Dizionario Inglese e Italiano, 1991:
"vegeto" (agg.) 1 thriving 2 (di persona) strong, vigorous. Vivo e vegeto, alive and kicking.